# ruby module NameError: uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to create a gem, but when trying to load a module in test I get the following error. I used "[Configurable Ruby gems: Custom error messages and testing](http://lizabinante.com/blog/configurable-ruby-gems-custom-errors-and-testing/)" to set environment variables from users and that's where most of the code is from.

```
  1) Msg91sms::Configuration with configuration block returns the correct authkey
     Failure/Error: raise Errors::Configuration, "Msg94 auth key missing!" unless @authkey

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Msg91sms::Configuration::Errors
     # ./lib/msg91sms/configuration.rb:10:in `authkey'
     # ./spec/msg91sms/configuration_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

but as per the folder structure and everything this should be `Msg91sms::Errors::Configuration`. I put only one here even though all tests are failing due to improper module loading.

The gem with this error can be found here: https://github.com/flyingboy007/msg91sms/tree/development

`bundle exec rspec` will throw all errors.

It should be something with naming or improper loading. But I can't figure out.

After following the answer by @sergio, I am now getting this error:

```
  1) Msg91sms::Configuration with configuration block returns the correct authkey
     Failure/Error: raise ::Msg91sms::Errors::Configuration, "Msg91 auth key missing!" unless @authkey

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Msg91sms::Errors
     # ./lib/msg91sms/configuration.rb:10:in `authkey'
     # ./spec/msg91sms/configuration_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it `Errors::Configuration` or `Configuration::Errors`?

Comment: The folder structure is like Errors::Configuration but the error is showing like Configuration::Errors..Dont know why..

Comment: `module Msg94sms
  module Errors
    class Configuration < StandardError; end
  end
end
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
raise Errors::Configuration, "Msg94 auth key missing!" unless @authkey
```

Use fully qualified name to help ruby lookup the class.

```
raise ::Msg91sms::Errors::Configuration, "Msg94 auth key missing!" unless @authkey
```

> The folder structure is like Errors::Configuration but the error is showing like Configuration::Errors..Dont know why..

It's trying to find `Errors::Configuration` within `Msg91sms::Configuration` (the current scope at that point). But since there's no `Msg91sms::Configuration::Errors`, it fails with that message.

Comment: looks like it was the issue there but now am getting a different error. Please see the update in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Abhilash: that is indeed another error, but I'll give you a hint. The file with that class is not loaded. How can you make it loaded? How do you load files in ruby?

Comment: indeed matee.. Thanks a lot for the info and the hint

Comment: First was an error i didnt think of... I looked at every possible thing I know about like loading and naming. With your help when  i solved I saw another error. But this time I stopped thinking as I thought it was something I didnt know about. But I was wrong again. I forget that simple thing..loading!!!! Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Abhilash: my pleasure :)